# For which values of x is the Gamma function Riemann Integrable?

Tags: gamma-function, riemann-integration

For which values of $x$ is the Gamma function $\Gamma (x) = \int\limits_0^{\infty}t^{x-1}e^{-t} dt$ Riemann Integrable?

I have read from elsewhere that the Gamma function converges for $x>0$, but:

1. What is the proof for $x>0$?
2. Does this itself (convergence) show that it is Riemann Integrable?
3. What about for $x\leq 0$?

Thanks!

Comment: (Riemann)-integrability is not defined pointwise, it makes no sense to ask for which values of $x$ some function $f(x)$ is integrable. I guess you are asking for which values of $x$ the integral $$\int_{0}^{+\infty} t^{x-1}e^{-t}\,dt $$ is convergent, and that is trivially for any $x>0$. Then you may check that $\Gamma(x)$, defined through such integral, is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^+$ (and much more, actually: it is a function with a convex logarithm).

Comment: It seem to me for all reals for which it is deifned, as it is continuous function. As far as I understand it is enough for Riemann integrability.

Comment: The usual argument is that $t^{x-1}e^{-\epsilon t} \to 0$ as $t \to +\infty$ whenever $\epsilon > 0$, therefore $|t^{x-1}e^{-t}| < Ce^{-t(1-\epsilon)}$ and $|\int_1^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt|<C \int_1^\infty e^{-t(1-\epsilon)} dt$ converges.
After that, you have to look at the convergence of $\int_0^1 t^{x-1} e^{-t}dt$

Answer (score 3):

You have

$$t^{x-1}e^{-t}\underset{t\to 0}{\sim} t^{x-1}$$

which is integrable on $(0,1]$ if and only if $x>0$.

And

$$t^{x-1}e^{-t}=\underset{t\to\infty}{o}(e^{-t/2})$$

which is always integrable on $[1,+\infty)$.

So, the integral defining $\Gamma(x)$ exists (i.e., converges) if, and only if, $x>0$.